# Add an item to the list with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to add new item to list using .append() but not work with my issue
I want to insert data into list like this :

```
hello = {}
```

why like this? I explained it with The code

```
hello = {} # I don't want to use with hello : []
# Because I'll use it to write into file like this : {u'list1': {'hello1': {}, 'hello2': {}}, u'list2': {'hello3': {}, 'hello4': {}}}

GoodWords = ["hello1", "hello2"]

def Write(filename, data):
    fp = file(filename, 'w')
    fp.write(data)
    fp.close()

"""
Here why I would like to use {} not []
It'll be write like this : {u'list1': {'hello1': {}, 'hello2': {}}}

def start():
    if not "list1" in hello:
        hello["list1"] = {}
    for x in GoodWords:
        hello["list1"][x] = {}
    Write("test.txt", str(hello))


"""

def start():
    # Any idea to use .append() with {} or something like
    for x in GoodWords:
        hello.append(x)

try: start(); sleep(4)
except Exception as why: print why
```

thanks.

Comment: hello = {} is a dictionary but not a list.

Comment: @m170897017 aha, mean I can't add new item ?

Comment: If you want to add a new item to a dictionary, just dictionary['new_key']='new_value'. 'new_value' could be any type of object you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `hello` is a dictionary, not a list.

Either use

`hello = []`

or

`hello[x] = "something"`